# ios using size classes

Tags: ios, size-classes

Using ios Size classes how do I differentiate between iphone 5.5inch in portrait and any other iphone in portrait.

For example if I set the text size - width compact and height any - this seems to apply to ALL iphones.  Is there a size class that you can apply to iphone 6 - that is different from all the other smaller iphones?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you have to do this programmatically.

Use this code to check for the size of the iPhone:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
    //3.5 inch iPhone
}
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    //4 inch iPhone
}
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667) {
    //4.7 inch iPhone
}
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736) {
    //5.5 inch iPhone
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to avoid this - I was hoping that one of the size classes would be able to differentiate - but it appears they only differentiate between iPAD and iPHONE (and the various orientations etc)